# Quickly locate an element from a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm developing a Python code to scrape a list of all dish names from this webpage: http://housing.ucdavis.edu/dining/menus/dining-commons/tercero/. I have basic knowledge of how HTML works and how to find elements by class name and I have successfully scraped some simpler web pages. It's just that this site has lots of dish names and every name is clickable, so the HTML file returned is super complex. Could someone provide an easier way to get a list of all the dish names after the user pick breakfast/lunch/dinner/late night? Thank you very much~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you tagged this as python, I'm assuming you want to use python rather than any other language option.

I find it easiest to use regular expressions to parse machine generated HTML. As it's generated by a template you can work out what the template is and pull out the values as named groups. Regular expressions are an INCREDIBLY powerful tool for processing text.

Using regular expressions also won't require that the HTML is well formed which I've seen a fair bit too. A SGML/ HTML parser will be less likely to work if the page has errors.

You can read up on regular expressions in the python manual https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html

If you haven't already discovered it, the requests library is great for fetching pages: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: Does that also work on the elements that are changing? I mean not the content of the element, but the number of elements. I originally cannot do the scraping because the dishes change every day and the number of dishes will be different.

Comment: Yup. Work out the pattern for one entry (it might be long!) and then use re.findall() to get a list of every match. You'll get a list of tuples, one entry in each tuple for each group. Alternatively you could use string.split() if you have a string that separates each item and match each of those.